# making windrose from my own data

Tags: python, ascii, file-read

I am trying to make a wind rose from a series of windspeed and direction values.  I have an idea of how to write the raw program for doing this as shown below:

```
from windrose import WindroseAxes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
ws=[2.6,2.3,2.1,2.0,2.1,2.2,2.9,2.8,2.39,1.90,1.54,1.29,0.72,0.18,1.08]
wd=[207,208,215,217,213,209,203,195,187,179,164,139,117,101,280]
print "WD is ",wd
print "WS is ",ws
ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(wd,ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
ax.set_legend()
plt.show()
```

The only issue is is how can I have the program reading my data into the arrays ws (windspeed) and wd (wind direction) in the above program.

The data is in an ascii file with two columns separated by a space.  The first column is wind speed and the second column is wind direction.

With wind speed in the first column and wind direction in the second column. Do you know how to read this type of wind using python so that column one occupies the ws array and column two occupies the wd array in the script above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.loadtxt`:

```
data = np.loadtxt('data.txt')
ws = data[:, 0]
wd = data[:, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a file named `data.csv` with the folowing content

```
2.6 207
2.3 208
2.1 215
2.0 217
2.1 213
2.2 209
2.9 203
2.8 195
2.39 187
1.90 179
1.54 164
1.29 139
0.72 117
0.18 101
1.08 280
```

You can use Pandas to read CSV file

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", names=["ws", "wd"], sep=" ")
ws = df["ws"].values
wd = df["wd"].values
```

PS: windrose can also directly use Pandas DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

in above code there is something wrong:

`ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()`: `WindroseAxes` has no attribute 'from_ax'

and also

`ax.bar(wd,ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')`:
`bar()` missing 1 required positional argument: 'var'

have a close look on it